# Boots to Emergency Console, Unable to check boot partition filesystem

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, boot-issues, raspbian-buster

Switched to F2FS for the root partition. Upgraded from stretch to buster by doing an `apt full-upgrade`. Now the system goes to the emergency console because the filesystem check dependency fails. It still boots after I hit ENTER. But, for the use case, that's not an acceptable solution. I'm mounting the boot partition from /dev/mmcblk0p1, so it's not a PARTUUID issue.

**Here's the journal:**

```
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: dev-mmcblk0p1.device: Job dev-mmcblk0p1.device/start timed out.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/mmcblk0p1.
-- Subject: A start job for unit dev-mmcblk0p1.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit dev-mmcblk0p1.device has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 22 and the job result is timeout.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1.
-- Subject: A start job for unit systemd-fsck@dev-mmcblk0p1.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit systemd-fsck@dev-mmcblk0p1.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 20 and the job result is dependency.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot.
-- Subject: A start job for unit boot.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit boot.mount has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 19 and the job result is dependency.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
-- Subject: A start job for unit local-fs.target has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit local-fs.target has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 16 and the job result is dependency.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: boot.mount: Job boot.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-mmcblk0p1.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-mmcblk0p1.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Feb 14 05:13:29 RaspPi systemd[1]: dev-mmcblk0p1.device: Job dev-mmcblk0p1.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

**sudo sfdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0**

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7.5 GiB, 8090812416 bytes, 15802368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcd18c759

Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1       8192    96042    87851 42.9M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      98304 15802367 15704064  7.5G 83 Linux
```

**sudo fsck.vfat -av /dev/mmcblk0p1**

```
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
 Automatically removing dirty bit.
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
       512 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
    346112 bytes per FAT (= 676 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 708608 (sector 1384)
     86467 data clusters (44271104 bytes)
32 sectors/track, 64 heads
         0 hidden sectors
     87851 sectors total
Reclaiming unconnected clusters.
Checking free cluster summary.
Performing changes.
/dev/mmcblk0p1: 220 files, 46381/86467 clusters
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- **sudo fsck.vfat -av /dev/mmcblk0p1**  (but the dirty bit keeps coming back after every reboot)
- Mounting by PARTUUID in /etc/fstab (no change)
- Deleting and recreating the partition and copying back the files (Thanks, [@goldilocks](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/5538/goldilocks))
- Reinstalled raspberrypi-kernel and raspberrypi-bootloader

Comment: I'd try copying everything off the boot partition, reformatting it (vfat), putting everything back.

Comment: @goldilocks Well, it was worth a shot. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: "*Upgraded from stretch to buster*" - did you install Raspbian Buster from the image or did you do an `sudo apt full-upgrade` on Stretch using the buster repository?

Comment: @Ingo I did the `apt full-upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

You have done an `apt full-upgrade` from Raspbian Stretch to Raspbian Buster. This can be done with **Debian** but for **Raspbian** it isn't official supported by the Raspberry Pi Foundation. It may be possible with some knowledge but they recommend to always start a new version from a fresh flashed image. If you encounter to problems after an `apt full-upgrade` they are based on undefined conditions which are not reproducible. I'm afraid you will not find much help about this situation and you are alone. Better start with a fresh flashed image.

Comment: That's good advice I think. I upgraded from `jessie` to `stretch` ["the hard way"](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/PackageMaintenance.md#version-upgrade) some time ago, but it seemed that *little issues* remained for some time afterwards.